# How do I hide the Task List and only show the Timeline

Tags: timeline

So, I just want to have the timeline showing at the top of the page and want to hide the task list below - is there a way to do that?

Thank You!

Comment: I will suggest you to create a new page and task list web part that will show time-line on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new view and select Gantt view.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to create a new page and task list web part that will show time-line on the page.

Else, you can add time-line on default list page and make default list web part as **hidden** from **web part properties**.

**Reference**:

[How to Hide a Web Part on SharePoint](https://www.dynamics101.com/how-to-hide-a-web-part-on-sharepoint/).